# How can I wait for a function to finish when I call it several times from another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, electron

I have tried many soltions (like async - await, promises, etc.), and I could't find somehing that really works.

I'm trying making a function that replaces text inside a file, it works but the problem ocurring when you try to replace couple of texts inside the same file.

That's the function:

```
function replaceInFile(tDir, orgTxt, txtTR) {
    console.log(`Dir: ${tDir} | orgTxt{ ${orgTxt} } txtTR.length{ ${txtTR.length} }`);
    fs.readFile(tDir, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(`DATA.LENGTH BR: ${data.length}`);
        let result = data.replace(orgTxt, txtTR);
        fs.writeFile(tDir, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
            console.log(`RESULT.LENGTH AW: ${result.length}`);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Another function calls the function as the folowing:

```
replaceInFile(destDir + 'word/header1.xml', /{{NAME}}/g, rabTxt + fullName);
replaceInFile(destDir + 'word/header1.xml', /{{DATE}}/g, `${day} ${month} ${year}`);
replaceInFile(destDir + 'word/document.xml', /{{HAXCABH}}/g, haxcaba);
replaceInFile(destDir + 'word/document.xml', /{{LETTERS}}/g, nameLetterSq(fullName));
replaceInFile(destDir + 'word/document.xml', /{{MRQY}}/g, isMrq());
```

The output I get not matter what I'm trying to do:

```
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/header1.xml | orgTxt{ /{{NAME}}/g } txtTR.length{ 14 }
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/header1.xml | orgTxt{ /{{DATE}}/g } txtTR.length{ 13 }
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/document.xml | orgTxt{ /{{HAXCABH}}/g } txtTR.length{ 2811 }
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/document.xml | orgTxt{ /{{LETTERS}}/g } txtTR.length{ 15647 }
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/document.xml | orgTxt{ /{{MRQY}}/g } txtTR.length{ 6919 } (2 times)
ON: "renderer.js:1299" - DATA.LENGTH BR: 4803 (3 times)
ON: "renderer.js:1299" - DATA.LENGTH BR: 43388
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: 4808
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: 59024
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: 50299
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: 46188
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: 4809
```

I want the function to run until it ends, so the desired output will be something like this (focusing on its order):

```
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/header1.xml | orgTxt{ /{{NAME}}/g } txtTR.length{ "Some Number" }
ON: "renderer.js:1299" - DATA.LENGTH BR: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/header1.xml | orgTxt{ /{{DATE}}/g } txtTR.length{ "Some Number" }
ON: "renderer.js:1299" - DATA.LENGTH BR: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/document.xml | orgTxt{ /{{HAXCABH}}/g } txtTR.length{ "Some Number" }
ON: "renderer.js:1299" - DATA.LENGTH BR: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/document.xml | orgTxt{ /{{LETTERS}}/g } txtTR.length{ "Some Number" }
ON: "renderer.js:1299" - DATA.LENGTH BR: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1294" - Dir: ./temporal/word/document.xml | orgTxt{ /{{MRQY}}/g } txtTR.length{ "Some Number" }
ON: "renderer.js:1299" - DATA.LENGTH BR: "Some Number"
ON: "renderer.js:1302" - RESULT.LENGTH AW: "Some Number"
```

The platform is "Electron" the code is in the "renderer.js" default file.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to turn your function into a promise and resolve the `promise` after writing the file.

```js
function replaceInFile(tDir, orgTxt, txtTR) {
    console.log(`Dir: ${tDir} | orgTxt{ ${orgTxt} } txtTR.length{ ${txtTR.length} }`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     fs.readFile(tDir, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err)
        }
        console.log(`DATA.LENGTH BR: ${data.length}`);
        let result = data.replace(orgTxt, txtTR);
        fs.writeFile(tDir, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
            console.log(`RESULT.LENGTH AW: ${result.length}`);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(result)
        });
     });
    })
}

(async () {
await replaceInFile(destDir + 'word/header1.xml', /{{NAME}}/g, rabTxt + fullName);
})()
```